# scsi_host interconnects

Tags: scsi

Can you please explain storage interconnects with respect to Linux. What are exactly scsi_host0, host1, host2, etc. I recently checked on a VM that had around 39 hosts present in /sys/class/scsi_hosts/ directory. Does it depend on the number of drives present in the server? Can you please guide here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the `scsi_host*` directories in `/sys/class/scsi_hosts` represent all SCSI-compatible storage controllers your system has. A single port of an AHCI SATA controller can each be one `scsi_host*` directory; the collection of all the USB storage devices on the system is typically represented by one `scsi_host*` directory; on servers with iSCSI or FibreChannel SAN adapters, each iSCSI of FibreChannel port can appear as a `scsi_host*` directory.

Basically, since so many storage protocols are either based on SCSI or related to it, representing them all as SCSI adapters defines a common set of basic operations that can be done with all of them.

On a virtual machine, the number and type of virtual storage controllers depends entirely on the design and configuration of the virtualization hypervisor. It's possible that your virtualization platform presents each virtual drive with a separate virtual controller, so that a virtual drive can be hot-removed if necessary with minimal effect to other virtual drives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by Channel in "A single channel of an AHCI SATA controller ......" And what is C "channel" in CTL when we scan an HBA for newly added LUN in a server? Is it a port of an HBA or what?

Comment: An AHCI SATA controller has typically 6 connections... well, perhaps a "port" would have been a better word choice there (edited). Some old parallel-SCSI HBAs may have multiple buses on them: the C number covers that.